# Как переписать в цикл агрегации объектов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, анализ-данных

```
    stats2 = stats.groupby([ha])[s].rolling(7,min_period=7).std(ddof=0).to_frame().reset_index()
    stats2[s] = stats2.groupby([ha])[s].shift(+1).fillna(0.01)
    stats2 = stats2.sort_values('level_1').reset_index()
    stats['std{}_{}'.format(d,s)] = stats2[s]

    stats2 = stats.groupby([ha])[s].rolling(7,min_period=7).mean().to_frame().reset_index()
    stats2[s] = stats2.groupby([ha])[s].shift(+1).fillna(0.01)
    stats2 = stats2.sort_values('level_1').reset_index()
    stats['mean{}_{}'.format(d,s)] = stats2[s]

    stats2 = stats.groupby([ha])[s].rolling(7,min_period=7).median().to_frame().reset_index()
    stats2[s] = stats2.groupby([ha])[s].shift(+1).fillna(0.01)
    stats2 = stats2.sort_values('level_1').reset_index()
    stats['median{}_{}'.format(d,s)] = stats2[s]
```

Как это переписать в цикл?

Данный пример для: `std`, `mean`, `median`.

Comment: а вы не могли бы _описать_ задачу, а не заставлять нас дебажить код? и пример вводных данных и желаемого результата не помешал бы.

Comment: там меняется агрегирующий метод и запись колонки

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Почему бы не воспользоваться стандартным методом `.agg('<method_name>')`:

```
def fun(df, method="mean", **kwargs)
    stats2 = df.groupby([ha])[s].rolling(7,min_period=7).agg(method, **kwargs).to_frame().reset_index()
    stats2[s] = stats2.groupby([ha])[s].shift(+1).fillna(0.01)
    stats2 = stats2.sort_values('level_1').reset_index()
    stats['std{}_{}'.format(d,s)] = stats2[s]
```

**Отказ от ответственности:** функция может содержать ошибки, т.к. в вопросе *отсутствует воспроизводимый пример данных*, который позволил бы протестировать работу функции.

---

**Прототип, построенный на игрушечном примере данных:**

DataFrame:

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(10, 3)), columns=list("abc"))

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   a  b  c
0  2  4  4
1  4  0  1
2  2  1  2
3  3  2  1
4  1  4  3
5  1  1  3
6  4  1  0
7  1  3  3
8  4  0  2
9  2  0  2
```

Проверка идеи:

```
In [20]: df.groupby("a")["b"].rolling(3, min_period=1).std(ddof=0)
Out[20]:
a
1  4         NaN
   5         NaN
   7    1.247219
2  0         NaN
   2         NaN
   9    1.699673
3  3         NaN
4  1         NaN
   6         NaN
   8    0.471405
Name: b, dtype: float64

In [21]: df.groupby("a")["b"].rolling(3, min_period=1).agg("std", ddof=0)
Out[21]:
a
1  4         NaN
   5         NaN
   7    1.247219
2  0         NaN
   2         NaN
   9    1.699673
3  3         NaN
4  1         NaN
   6         NaN
   8    0.471405
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

---

PS после создания функции можно в цикле вызывать функцию с различными аргументами.

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо.

Answer (score 4):

Ну как-то так, наверное:

```
for method in ['std', 'mean', 'median']:

    stats2 = stats.groupby([ha])[s].rolling(7,min_period=7)

    if method == 'std':
        stats2 = stats2.std(ddof=0)
    elif method == 'mean':
        stats2 = stats2.mean()
    elif method == 'median':
        stats2 = stats2.mean()
    else:
        # тут как-то обработать ошибку "неизвестный метод"
        pass

    stats2 = stats2.to_frame().reset_index()
    stats2[s] = stats2.groupby([ha])[s].shift(+1).fillna(0.01)
    stats2 = stats2.sort_values('level_1').reset_index()
    stats[method + '{}_{}'.format(d,s)] = stats2[s]
```

Как сами методы через список передать не соображу. Но вообще можно через `partial` попробовать, если очень нужно.

Набросал вариант через `partial`, попробуйте:

```
from pandas.core.window import Rolling
from functools import partial

for method,func in [('std',partial(Rolling.std, ddof=0)), ('mean',Rolling.mean), ('median',Rolling.median)]:

    stats2 = stats.groupby([ha])[s].rolling(7,min_period=7)
    stats2 = func(stats2)
    stats2 = stats2.to_frame().reset_index()
    stats2[s] = stats2.groupby([ha])[s].shift(+1).fillna(0.01)
    stats2 = stats2.sort_values('level_1').reset_index()
    stats[method + '{}_{}'.format(d,s)] = stats2[s]
```

Comment: @AlexandrKosolapov Добавил вариант с `partial` для функции с параметром и прочими функцями без параметров, попробуйте.

Comment: спасибо, в будущем буду иметь в виду этот приём, но выше ответили по методу agg, который как раз решает задачу

Comment: @AlexandrKosolapov Да, через `agg` это правильный подход, главное потом нормально разобрать результат